# how to validate username minlength and show error message with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

When working with form validation i want to show the instant error message when usename length is
less than specific length. But the problem is that, suppose i want to show the error when length is less than 4, onchange i get the error but when it's less than 4 but when i reduce the length error not showing again.

```
  const [signUpValues, setSignUpValues] = useState({
    userName: "",
  });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    userNameErr: ""
  });

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setSignUpValues({ ...signUpValues, [name]: value });

    switch (name) {
      case "userName":
        setErrors({
          ...errors,
          userNameErr:
            signUpValues.userName.length < 4
              ? "Username should be atleast 4 char."
              : ""
        });
        break;
      default:
        setErrors({});
    }
  };

  const validateSignUp = signUpValues => {
    let isValid = false;
    if (signUpValues.userName.length > 4 ) {
      isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
  };

  const signUpHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateSignUp(signUpValues)) {
    } else if (!signUpValues.userName) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, allFieldRequired: "Please fill all the fields." });
    } else {
      setErrors({ ...errors, allFieldRequired: "" });
    }
  };
```

Comment: when i focus on input error message show till the length is less than 4 when it's reach to the 4 error message gone, till now everything is ok, but when i tried to reduce length back message should be there but it's not there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that state doesn't update instantly, so your code enters the switch before the state of the name has updated.

To fix this, you can make use of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and check the state of the name after it has been processed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  switch(name){
    //name validation
  }
}, [name]);
```

Comment: can i put switch statement with in useEffect?

Comment: yeah, of course. You can inside it make a switch on the name state

Comment: plz help me to do this with in useEffect for username, email and password

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!validateSignUp(signUpValues)) {
    setErrors({
          ...errors,
          userNameErr:"Username should be atleast 4 char."
        });
    } else if (!signUpValues.userName) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, allFieldRequired: "Please fill all the fields." });
    } else {
      setErrors({ ...errors, allFieldRequired: "" });
    }
```